# Moving text on a page with iText7 retaining font, color, style, ... but changing size of the text

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I want to move text with iText7. I have a source bounding box, that can be somewhere on the page and I have a target bounding box, that has a fixed position (incl. width and height). I'll stay on the same page. The source and target boxes can overlap. The source bounding box can also be larger than the target box. In this case I have to reduce the font size. The text should retain font, color and so on.

There is a [cut and paste example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-cut-and-paste-content-page) on the iText website . But in the result pdf file you can select the text at the new and old position (tried it only with a normal pdf reader). I don't want the text to be selectable at the old position.

I thought, that maybe I could select the text and just place it at the new position and remove it from the old position. For the latter i would need pdfSweep, but this is ok. Adding the text at the new position should be no problem. Even if the text has different fonts, sizes and so on. There are plenty of examples on the iText website. The only way I know to select the text is like shown in this [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/content-parsing-extraction-and-redaction-text/itext7-how-read-text-specific-position). This gives me only the text. But to place it at the target position with the same font, color and so on, I need all those informations, too. 
I know, that pdf is not meant for editing. This is often mention in answers on StackOverflow.
Is there a way to do this with iText7?

Comment: Can you share a typical example PDF with typical source and target boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no high level API in iText allowing you to *move* page content, in particular not *all content from some rectangle*. One reason may be that in general this is no mere moving. PDFs often contain structures influencing larger areas, and such structures would not simply have to be moved but instead copied, and each copy restricted to its area.

It is indeed possible, though, to combine the [cut and paste example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-cut-and-paste-content-page) the OP found with the pdfSweep module already considered by the OP to a solution which prevents *the text from being selectable at the old position,* e.g. like this:

```
public void moveCleanSection(PdfReader pdfReader, String targetFile, int page, Rectangle from, Rectangle to) throws IOException
{
    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("itextkey-multiple-products.xml");

    ByteArrayOutputStream interimMain = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream interimPage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream interimSection = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (   PdfDocument pdfMainDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
            PdfDocument pdfPageDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(interimPage)) )
    {
        pdfMainDocument.setCloseReader(false);
        pdfMainDocument.copyPagesTo(page, page, pdfPageDocument);
    }

    try (   PdfDocument pdfMainDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, new PdfWriter(interimMain));
            PdfDocument pdfSectionDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(interimPage.toByteArray())), 
            new PdfWriter(interimSection))  )
    {

        List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
        cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(page, from, null));
        cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(page, to, null));

        PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfMainDocument, cleanUpLocations);
        cleaner.cleanUp();

        cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
        Rectangle mediaBox = pdfSectionDocument.getPage(1).getMediaBox();

        if (from.getTop() < mediaBox.getTop())
            cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(mediaBox.getLeft(), from.getTop(), mediaBox.getWidth(), mediaBox.getTop() - from.getTop()), null));
        if (from.getBottom() > mediaBox.getBottom())
            cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(mediaBox.getLeft(), mediaBox.getBottom(), mediaBox.getWidth(), from.getBottom() -  mediaBox.getBottom()), null));
        if (from.getLeft() > mediaBox.getLeft())
            cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(mediaBox.getLeft(), mediaBox.getBottom(), from.getLeft() - mediaBox.getLeft(), mediaBox.getHeight()), null));
        if (from.getRight() < mediaBox.getRight())
            cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(from.getRight(), mediaBox.getBottom(), mediaBox.getRight() - from.getRight(), mediaBox.getHeight()), null));

        cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfSectionDocument, cleanUpLocations);
        cleaner.cleanUp();
    }

    try (   PdfDocument pdfSectionDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(interimSection.toByteArray())));
            PdfDocument pdfMainDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(interimMain.toByteArray())), new PdfWriter(targetFile)) )
    {
        float scale = Math.min(to.getHeight() / from.getHeight(), to.getWidth() / from.getWidth());
        pdfSectionDocument.getPage(1).setMediaBox(from);
        PdfFormXObject pageXObject = pdfSectionDocument.getFirstPage().copyAsFormXObject(pdfMainDocument);
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfMainDocument.getPage(page);
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
        pdfCanvas.addXObject(pageXObject, scale, 0, 0, scale, (to.getLeft() - from.getLeft() * scale), (to.getBottom() - from.getBottom() * scale));
    }
}
```

*(From [MoveSectionCleanly.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/cleanup/MoveSectionCleanly.java#L69))*

Beware: Due to the nature of pdfSweep, text being on the border of the source area is removed both from the source and the copy of it.

Comment: Sorry for my (very) late reply. Thank you very much. Making a copy of the section, scaling it and putting it onto the page didn't come to my mind.